# add shadow to layout programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin

So I have many `LinearLayouts` and `RelativeLayouts` that I need to apply shadows to. But all these layouts will have different background color.

For example, I have 3 LinearLayouts.  I need one Blue, One Green and One Red but all will have the same shadows and style (except for the color).

I already have these layouts created so what can I do to apply shadows to them manually?

If I create an XML drawable then I have to create a different drawable for each color.  Is there any other way I can do this?

I was thinking about making a common function where I can pass either a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and apply the shadow effects with a specific solid color as background.

But I am not sure if there is a way to apply shadow programmatically.  Please let me know what my choices are.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need [Outline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html). Since you mention that you want to do this programmatically Outline will do the trick. Fetch your layouts by `findViewById()`, use `getOutlineProvider()` from your layouts, get the `ViewOutlineProvider` then use the `getoutline()` method to set a custom Outline object that you will create as a shadow to any `View` that you desire. (also check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html) from the official documentation)

As for what your choices are I would have to say that generally speaking you have 2 choices.

1) Implement the shadows via XML declarations as a property of any other `View` that you inflate

2) Do it programmatically with Outline.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such attribute in Android, to show a shadow. But possible ways to do it are:

1)Add a plain LinearLayout/RelativeLayout with colors, over which add your actual layout, with margin at bottom and right equal to 1 or 2 dp

2)Have a 9-patch image with a shadow and set it as the background to your Linear layout/RelativeLayout